# iOS: Storing data in memory rather than on disk

Tags: ios, core-data, in-memory-database, nspersistentstore

I'm looking for a tutorial on how to store sensitive data in memory rather than on disk for iOS (10+). I've googled but nothing really relevant has come up.

I'm familiar with most data storage options for iOS, SQLite, Plist, Core Data, User Defaults and Keychain. I know Core Data has an in-memory persistent store option but am not sure how to designate that as the one I want to use. Looking at the Apple docs and other tutorials I've only seen the instantiation of a persistent store but not declaring whether it was to be sqlite or core data or in-memory.

For example, Apple's docs on the Core Data stack:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
class DataController: NSObject {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    init(completionClosure: @escaping () -> ()) {
        persistentContainer = NSPersistentContainer(name: "DataModel")
        persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores() { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
                fatalError("Failed to load Core Data stack: \(error)")
            }
            completionClosure()
        }
    }
}
```

This question seems to point in the right direction (just the code initially posted)

[Save In-Memory store to a file on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25015277/save-in-memory-store-to-a-file-on-ios)

```
- (NSPersistentStore *)addPersistentStoreWithType:(NSString *)storeType configuration:(NSString *)configuration URL:(NSURL *)storeURL options:(NSDictionary *)options error:(NSError **)error;
```

Is it just that, passing a type? And to follow-up, once the app closes, the in-memory data is released?

Thanks

Comment: Yep. See the docs on `NSInMemoryStoreType`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using `NSPersistentContainer`, you tell Core Data what kind of store to use with an instance of `NSPersistentStoreDescription`. It has a property called `type` that accepts values like `NSInMemoryStoreType`. Set up a description and then assign that to the container's `persistentStoreDescriptions` property, and you'll get an in-memory store. The method you mention would work but would require changing your Core Data setup to drop `NSPersistentContainer`.

It exists, as the name implies, only in memory, so anything stored there disappears when the app exits.

Comment: Thanks Tom, just what I was looking for.